# TYPO3 RTE (htmlarea) - How can I disable options on Link Wizard (mail,file, etc.)

Tags: hyperlink, typo3, config, wizard, rte

in Backend TYPO3: How can I disable one of these options on RTE (htmlarea), when the editor click on the LINK-Button (anchor). The Link Wizard starts in new window and the editor can choose the link to a page, folder, mail or ext. website.

I want to remove some of these options. Only "Page" and "Mail" will be allowed.

I thought it was on the pageconfig.ts

```
RTE.default.blindlinkoptions = spec,url
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone an idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There it is:

```
RTE.default.buttons.link.options.removeItems = page,file,url,mail,spec, folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
RTE.default.FE.classesAnchor.default.url > 
RTE.default.FE.classesAnchor.default.file >
```

or this, or both:

```
RTE.default.FE.classesAnchor := removeFromList(internal-link,
    internal-link-new-window, mail)
```

I'm not so sure about this solutions. I just looked the pathes up in the Backend in the Info module under PageTSConfig.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. Not alone, not together ... nothing. I've cleared the cache after every change. My pagetsConfig is a ext. file.

Comment: Yeah right, this only removes the classes from those links. Sorry, still thinking what could help :)

Comment: I've tried "RTE.default.blindLinkOptions = spec,file,url,mail" like FlexForm-Parameters,  but it doesn't work ...

Comment: I've read the manual, bit I can't find it, so I post it here ;)    It's not blindlinkOptions.